# Android SDK plug-in appears to impact Eclipse heavily

Tags: android, eclipse

Am I the only Eclipse developer whose workbench quickly sputters, wheezes, crashes or hangs and makes me use Windows 7 Task Manager to hard-bounce it?

I've got dedicated, Android-only (as it were) installations of Eclipse Helios (3.6) and Galileo (3.5) with the very latest Android SDK (0.9.7.v201005071157-36220) using android-sdk_r06-windows.zip. I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, but 32-bit Eclipse (Helios and Galileo) and a 32-bit jdk1.6.0_20.

It is true that these are both Eclipse Java EE installations and not the bare-bones Java-only (non-WTP) versions. I haven't tried that yet. I followed a tutorial that said to use Helios, but said nothing about what not to include (like WTP which I ordinarily use in my work).

I can avoid much of the trouble by editing XML files using the standard Eclipse XML Editor and avoiding the Android SDK's various XML editors, but very quickly, things stop working and the whole thing caves in on itself.

I've tried bumping memory in *eclipse.ini*, -Xms128m, but that hasn't helped.

I'm looking to hear from someone who's gotten over this mess or who knows what I should have done.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any and all comments.

Russ Bateman

Comment: i have SDK, emulator, and eclipse plugin all on Win7 laptop. Eclipse take ~500MB RAM. i do not have any such problem yet.
(win7 is 64bit, emulator is 32bit, eclipse is 64bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of frustration I reached the conclusion that you cannot install Android for use in Eclipse Java EE, my usual mode. Instead, use the plain Java Eclipse. My definitive installation became Eclipse Galileo SR2 IDE for Java Developers. I added these lines to *eclipse.ini*, though I probably did not have to be so generous:

```
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

In order to distinguish this version of Eclipse from my usual Java EE development version on my task bar, I found an icon to graft onto it at http://www.large-icons.com/stock-icons/free-large-android-icons.htm and selected one that looked most like the green Android icon.

Comment: I thought I'd come back with a parting remark. Even at its best, I find that my 3.5SP2 (Galileo) Eclipse with Android (and nothing else) goes south about once every hour or so. When it does, I sometimes have to bounce my Windows machine because the workspace is unhealthy (wont' start, Windows thinks something's open) and this results in my having to set up Eclipse perspectives and views all over again. I also more recently began developing for BlackBerry in parallel. Eclipse with BlackBerry is solid; nothing like this ever happens. Hope this comment helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` to your eclipse.ini file right after `-vmargs`. I have no idea why, but apparently it's a known bug. I can get you the source where I found this solution if you'd like, it took me a fair bit of googling

Comment: This does seem to improve things. I'll work with it more today and tomorrow, then report back whether I have much to say or not. Thank you very much!

Comment: I also have the same problem.. tried your fix will let you know if this works

Comment: @Russ - Can you post a stack trace from your crash log? It's in `<workspace>\.metadata\.log`

Comment: Ultimately, this isn't better. Eclipse still crashes 6 ways from Sunday. After trying several values, I've presently got:
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m